# Amazon Marketplace Web Services in Azure Data Factory - Error multiple values AWSAccessKeyId?

Tags: amazon-web-services, datasource, azure-data-factory

We are struggling to connect with Azure Data Factory to Amazon Marketplace Web Services.
It seems that we have all information required, however, we are getting the following error:

**Parameter AWSAccessKeyId cannot have multiple values.**

All data seems to be correct. However, we think it is strange that a Access Key Id and Secret Access Key are needed to connect to the Marketplace Web Services. Both keys come from the AWS environment which is currently not connected to anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards,

Jens

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need **Access key ID** and **Secret key** while creating the Amazon Marketplace Web Service linked service in Azure Data Factory. **There should only be one Access Key assigned to per user in AWS Marketplace.** Apart from this, other properties are also required. Please refer below image for the same. Some properties are mandatory and others not.

[image]

To allow people in your company to sign in to the AWS Marketplace Management Portal, create an IAM user for each person who needs access.

**To create IAM users**

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the IAM console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Users and then choose Create New Users.
3. In the numbered text boxes, enter a name for each user that you want to create.
4. Clear the Generate an access key for each user check box and then choose Create.

This key now you will pass in Linked Service in ADF.

Also, for better security, you can save the `SecretKey` in Azure Key Vault and use Azure Key Vault Linked Service to access the `SecretKey`. Refer [Store credentials in Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/store-credentials-in-key-vault).